# NotInTransactionException with neo4j embedded version 2.3.8

Tags: java, neo4j

I have upgraded neo4j embedded version 1.9.8 to 2.3.8, Post upgrade server is up. But getting NotInTransactionException from below code. Seems some issue with index

```
 protected Record getNext() throws Exception {
    if (hits == null) {
        hits = index.query(query);
    }
    T next = hits.next();
    if (next == null) {
        return finished();
    } else {
        return nodeToRecord.call(next);
    }
}
```

Below is the error. My class name is GraphNodeIterator

```
Unexpected error : org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.assertInUnterminatedTransaction(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:72)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.getTopLevelTransactionBoundToThisThread(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:106)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.getKernelTransactionBoundToThisThread(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:113)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.get(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:65)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.LegacyIndexProxy.query(LegacyIndexProxy.java:363)
at com.nodalgeography.graph.GraphNodeIterator.getNext(GraphNodeIterator.java:32)
at com.nodalgeography.graph.GraphNodeIterator.getNext(GraphNodeIterator.java:14)
at com.googlecode.totallylazy.iterators.StatefulIterator.hasNext(StatefulIterator.java:23)
at com.googlecode.totallylazy.iterators.StatefulIterator.next(StatefulIterator.java:36)
at com.googlecode.totallylazy.Computation$2.call(Computation.java:80)
at com.googlecode.totallylazy.callables.LazyCallable.get(LazyCallable.java:19)
at com.googlecode.totallylazy.Lazy.call(Lazy.java:22)
at com.googlecode.totallylazy.Computation.isEmpty(Computation.java:121)
at com.googlecode.totallylazy.iterators.SegmentIterator.hasNext(SegmentIterator.java:18)
```

Comment: Generally a `NotInTransactionException`  is related to something you do in your code that must be wrapped by a transaction (no link to index). To help you can you give us the code of `GraphNodeIterator` ? Moreover Neoj 2.3.8 is quite old, why are you not upgrading to Neo4j 3.X ?

Comment: Issue is resolved post creating Transaction Instance. First i tried upgrading to 3.X, but i got an error like there is no direct upgrade for 1.9.8 to 3.X. So i tied to upgrade to 2.3.8 since it is stable version.